# Why does the animations slowly stops when I am in a different tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Why does the animations slowly stops when I am in a different tab or when window is minimized?

It's this codepen link - http://codepen.io/heyjules/pen/LVoEOw

It works fine at first. But then once you tab out or minimize (for about 5- 10 sec), The "particles" have lessened.

Why does it do this? How do I stop this from happening?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Particles</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #canvas {
            cursor: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="particles.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers the timers (setTimeout, setInterval, setImmediate and requestAnimationFrame) are set to not fire more often than once per second in inactive tabs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Inactive_tabs

Comment: Ah i see now I understand. Thank you. But the thing is it doesn't go back to being active once I go back to the tab. I gotta refresh the page for it to be active again. Do you know any solutions for this?

Comment: @billybobjones, for me it works ok, at least I do not see any differences while switching back from another tab or window, may be it's something browser related?